# How can I exclude a character from a regex capturing group?

Tags: regex

I have a regex capture, and I would like to exclude a character (a space, in this particular case) from the *middle* of the captured string. Can this be done in one step, by modifying the regex?

(Quick and dirty) example:

```
Text: Key name = value
My regex: (.*) = (.*)
Output: \1 = "Key name" and \2 = "value"
Desired output: \1 = "Keyname" and \2 = "value"
```

**Update:** I'm not sure what regex engine will run this regex, since it's part of a larger software product. If you have a solution, please specify which engines it will run on, and on which it will not.

**Update2:** The aforementioned product takes a regex as an input, and then uses the matched values further, which is the reason for which a one-step solution is asked for. There is no opportunity to insert an intermediate processing step in the pipeline.

Comment: Can't you replace that after the match?

Comment: What is the language? It is difficult to render appropriate help without knowing the programming language the regex will be used in. As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: @stribizhev, the full solution may depend on the language, but the answer to the question doesn't.  You can't do that in a single regex match in any regex flavor.  You have to match the whole thing and remove the spaces afterward.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Why do you address me? I know that.

Comment: @stribizhev: On reflection, I realize that was a canned comment that you posted simply because there's no "flavor" tag.  It's good general advice, but you should make it clear that it **is** general advice.  Because you seem to be implying that it's relevant in *this* case, when it isn't.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Why do you insist we do not need to know the language? One of the answers uses `\G` - it won't work with Python `re` or with JavaScript. Knowing the language/tool is *always* important.

Comment: The question linked seems to be indeed a duplicate, however the answer is that it's impossible :(

Comment: @stribizhev:  That answer misses the point of the question.  Dan is asking how to skip over characters in the course of a single match, which can't be done in any flavor.

Comment: @DanNestor: There is no way to match non-continuous text in just one match operation.

Comment: Hm... not sure if I need a single match though. What I meant by "one step" was that I can't use a subsequent replace operation as some might have suggested (indeed, the answer would have been trivial). I will test to see if a multiple-match solution works in my tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible theoretical pure-regex implementation using the end-of-previous-match `\G` anchor:

```
/(?:\G(\w+)\h(?:(?:=\h)(\w+))?)+/g
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL3rN3/4)

**Legenda**

```
(?:           # Non capturing group 1
  \G          # Matches where the regex engine stops in the previous step
  (\w+)       # capture group 1: a regex word of 1+ chars
  \h*         # zero or more horizontal spaces (space, tabs)
  (?:         # Non capturing group 2
    =\h*      # literal '=' follower by zero or more hspaces
    (\w+)     # capture group 2: a regex word of 1+ chars
  )?          # make the non capturing group 2 optional
)+            # repeat the non capturing group 1, one or more
```

In the substitution section of the demo:

- `\1` actually contains `Keyname` (the 2 terms are separated by a fake space)
- `\2` is `value`

*NOTE*: i don't recommend using this unless actually needed (why?).

There are multiple possible approaches in 2 steps: as surely already stated simply strip spaces from the first capturing group of the OP regex.

Comment: The question states clearly that a one-step solution is needed. Is there any particular reason behind you saying that you don't recommend your solution?

Comment: Your solution doesn't produce the expected result, and I don't understand it enough to modify it myself. Could you edit it (if it's possible) to satisfy the requirements in the question?

Comment: @DanNestor: explain me why a one step solution is required, i found interesting trying to solve your problem but i think that with a complete explanation of the details your question will be better received. In any case ``\G`` is not available in some regex engine. For what i know without ``\G`` is not possible to satisfy all your constraints.

Comment: `\G` works fine by itself, there's no need to wrap it in a lookbehind.

Comment: @GsusRecovery I'm not sure why the motives have to be explained for a question to be better received, but since you ask, it's because I do not have the opportunity to run a second step. As stated in the question, this regex will be used in a software product, and the product  takes a regex as an input, and then uses the matched values further.

Comment: @DanNestor: if it's not clear, explain just for spare your time. You avoid answers of people that tell you: "why don't you do this way instead?" without counting the people that asks you "why do you want to do this way?"

Comment: @GsusRecovery yeah, I hoped that I will get this result by stating that I need a one-step solution. :)

Answer (score -1):

I would come up with sth. like:

```
(?<key>[\w]+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.+)
# look for a word character and capture it in a group called "key"
# followed by zero or unlimited times of a whitespace character (\s)
# followed by an equation sign
# followed by zero or unlimited times of a whitespace character (\s)
# capture the rest in a group called value
```

... and process the captured output afterwards. But with the `\w` character class no whitespace will matched (do you have keys with a whitespace in it?).
See a [working demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eE0sE0/2). But as mentionned in the comments, it depends on your programming language.